# iOS removeObjectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c

Good day!

I have this code to remove the a particular `database` in a NSMutableArray.

```
-(void)removeDatabaseName:(NSString*)databaseName {
    // remove database from array of databases
    for (int index = 0; index < [[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"databaseName"] count]; index++) {
        if ([[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"databaseName"] objectAtIndex:index] == databaseName) {

            //Match
            [[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"database"] removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            [[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"databaseName"] removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            [[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"location"] removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            NSLog(@"removed database");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, it displays the **NSLog(@"removed database");** but I don't know if it was totally removed in the NSMutableArray or if I am wrong can I have at least remove the specific file?

Comment: You need to explain your situation more. What is self.openDatabases and what are you trying to do with it? What do you mean you don't know if it was totally removed? How could it be partially removed? Why can't you just check what's in it to see if it was properly deleted?

Comment: self.openDatabase is a NSMutableArray

Comment: Can you please explain your situation bit more. - objectForKey wont work for MutableArray. It seems its a Dictionary, and [self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"databaseName"] gives array in return. On that basis you look objectAtIndex: for "index". Which gives a string to compare. Why dont you print "self.openDatabases" and check it out is is really removed or not.